# Unknown Publisher in Set Up project in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects to create a set up project for my WPF application using .NetCore in Visual Studio 2019.
How can I change the publisher from unknown to known when installing the application?

Answer (score -1):

You can insert a pulisher under:

Properties-> Assembly informations
[image]

Comment: @DenisScharf thank you for your help! I wasn't able to add the publisher's name here. However, I managed to add it in the .csproj file. Unfortunately, it still shows that the publisher's name is unknown